# Finding fixed points algebraically

Tags: real-analysis, fixed-points

I am working on the following problem:

Consider the function

$f: [-1,1] \mapsto \mathbb{R}, f(x) = x(x-1)(x+1)$

What are the fixed points of $f$? What are the fixed points if we extend the domain to $[-2,2]$?

I would be able to show the existence of the fixed point(s) with the Intermediate Value Theorem but I don't know how to find the specific values for where the fixed points are. How does one do this?

Comment: Note that a fixed point of $f$ is a zero (root) of $g(x) = f(x) - x$.  So solving for fixed points "algebraically" is no easier (or harder) than solving for roots.

Answer (score 1):

@hardmath pointed out in his comment that finding the fixed points of $f$ is related to finding the roots of $g(x)=f(x)-x=x^3-2x$. We see immediately that $x=0$ is a fixed point. Any other fixed points hence must satisfy
$$x^2=2\quad\text{or, equivalently}\quad x=\pm\sqrt 2.$$
$\pm\sqrt 2$ are fixed points if and only if they are in the domain of $f$.